# How do I make my flip card page responsive?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make my page responsive but I don't seem to be able to make it happen. When I check using the inspect element, the page is responsive but when I use my phone, the page doesn't rescale. Can anyone possibly tell me what went wrong. I doesn't seem to be responsive because of the flip card.

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

</head>
<body>

<div class="happy-birthday">
<h1> happy birthday </h1>
</div>

<div class="flip-card">
<div class="flip-card-inner">

<div class="flip-card-front">
<img src="front.jpg">
</div>

<div class="card-side-shadow">
<img src="card_shadow.png">
</div>

<div class="flip-card-back">
<img src="back.jpg">
</div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: 'cervanttisregular';
src: url('cervanttis-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('cervanttis-webfont.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

.happy-birthday
{
text-align: center;
color: pink;
font-family: 'cervanttisregular';
}

.flip-card
{
text-align: center;
width: 960px;
margin: 0px auto;
}

.flip-card-inner
{
position: relative;
transition: transform 1.0s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-card-back
{
transform: rotateY(180deg);
z-index: 1;
}

.card-side-shadow
{
opacity: 1;
right: 312px;
}

.flip-card-back, .flip-card-front, .card-side-shadow
{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner
{
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 959px)
{
.happy-birthday
{
width: 100%;
}
.flip-card
{
width: 100%;
}
.flip-card-inner
{
width: 100%;
}
.flip-card-front
{
width: 100%;
}
.flip-card-back
{
width: 100%;
}
.card-side-shadow
{
width: 100%;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
.happy-birthday
{
width: 100%;
}
.flip-card
{
width: 100%;
}
.flip-card-inner
{
width: 100%;
}
.flip-card-front
{
width: 100%;
}
.flip-card-back
{
width: 100%;
}
.card-side-shadow
{
width: 100%;
}
}
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: Hi. It is easier to help if you add the corresponding html in your question. It seems you have used a fixed width 960px on the `.flip-card` selector. This is wider than a smartphone is able to display.

Comment: Hi, I've already added the html code. Hope you can help. Thanks btw for the comment

Answer (score 1):

This is a responsive example. You can change it in a way you like.

First of all, the img must be responsive with an `height: auto;`. Then, by using the @media breakpoints, the flip-card gets a width that will not exceed the width of the browser view. The `margin: 0px auto;` will center the card horizontally on the page.

Font "sans-serif" has been added to the font-family as fall-back if the woff2/woff files are not there.

If you remove all @media parts from the css then the image will be ful width

**Update** Safari does not support `backface-visibility:hidden` [without the prefix -webkit-](https://caniuse.com/?search=backface-visibility) so this is added at selector: flip-card-back, flip-card-front

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'cervanttisregular';
  src: url('cervanttis-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('cervanttis-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
.happy-birthday {
  text-align: center;
  color: pink;
  font-family: 'cervanttisregular', sans-serif;
}
.flip-card {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .flip-card {
    width: 540px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .flip-card {
    width: 730px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .flip-card {
    width: 960px;
  }
}
.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1.0s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.flip-card-inner img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
}
.flip-card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  z-index: 1;
}
.card-side-shadow {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flip-card-back,
.flip-card-front,
.card-side-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="happy-birthday">
  <h1> happy birthday </h1>
</div>

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/9cc/fff.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/cc9/fff.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The head section looks like this

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bron. Really appreciate your help. It really works and Im so happy. Thank you thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Success with your project.

Comment: Hi Bron, I have another problem. When I run the code, it worked just fine but not on safari. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: It seems that Safari does not support `backface-visibility` so for Safari the -webkit- prefix property must be added. I updated the code above.